# Why are these two problems equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations

I have a problem for which I don't know how to give a "fluent" explanation of it.
Here is the problem, I have the following recursion

$$
P_k(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
(2k-1)xP_{k-1}(x) + (1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}P_{k-1}(x) & k \geq 2 \\
1 & k = 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

And from this recursion I want to express the coefficients of $P_k$ given the ones of $P_{k-1}$. I already know that for each $k$ the polynomial is at most of degree $k-1$, so for each $k$ the expression is like

$$
P_k(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_{j,k}x^j
$$

However I preferred to tackle the problem in the following way, I've studied the "equivalent problem":

$$
U_k(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
(2k-1)xU_{k-1}(x) + (1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}U_{k-1}(x) & k \geq 2 \\
1 & k = 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Where

$$
U_k(x) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} b_{j,k}x^j
$$

And I've found this problem more useful because it allows me to neglect some boundary conditions that comes out. Anyway... my question is... how can I justify that the two problems expressed in terms of $P_k$ and $U_k$ are equivalent?

Comment: If $P$ and $U$ you mean the limit value, basically yes.

Comment: Corrected,thanks.

Comment: The recursions for the $P_k$ and $U_k$ are the same, so they are equal and of the first sum type. I do not see a reason why negative exponents should occur.

Comment: As I said, the problem is when I express the coefficients of $P_k$ in terms of the ones of $P_{k-1}$, treating  the problem using the $U$ functions is better.

Comment: I am not sure that I perfectly understood your question and, moreover, I am not a specialist in differentiable functions, but maybe the problem consists of the functions $P_k$ and $U_k$, in general, may have different domains of the existence; but, nevertheless, they may (or should) coincide on the intersection of their domains (see, for instance [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884738/is-int-0-infty-fracdtet-xt-analytic-continuation-of-sum-k-1-infty) question.