# What is an example of analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I’ve always heard of the idea of analytic continuation in th context of complex analysis, but what is one example that I could understand? If you could, please give an example that a Precalculus student would understand, and one that someone who is taking calculus can understand. For example, is finding the value of a logarithm of complex/negative numbers and example of analytic continuation?

Comment: See this question for a nice example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884738/269624

Comment: Read about the famous Riemann Zeta function for another example. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function